# acts_taggable_on not recording tagger_id or tagger_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have setup the acts-as-taggable-on gem on Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2. The tagging is working as expected but the taggings table is not capturing the tagger_id.

Here is what I have setup:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  # attr_accessible :title, :description, :duration, :format

  acts_as_taggable

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # identifies user who tags as part of the acts-as-taggable-on gem
  acts_as_tagger
```

Thanks in advance for any help identifying what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Acts-as-taggable-on has no way to automatically know which user is doing the tagging. When a user enters or edits a Course, in the controller you have to explicitly tell it that the user is tagging the class as follows:

@user.tag(@class, :with => "tag1, tag2")

It's in the documentation under the heading Tag Ownership:

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on